# capture cis transient convergence problem

Tags: pspice

I have this schematics and I want op amp to saturate but I am not able to finish simulation due to convergence error. I have tried add 1 ohm resistance,1p capacitance to circuit, reduce ABSTOL to 10uA, reduce RELTOL to 0.1 ohm, reduce minimal step to 100ps and change iteration metod in setting but without success. Any suggestions?

```
Reducing minimum delta to make the circuit converge.

ERROR(ORPSIM-15138): Convergence problem in Transient Analysis at Time =  2.710E-06.
         Time step =  186.3E-21, minimum allowable step size =  1.000E-18

  These voltages failed to converge:

    V(X_U1.44)                =    540.58V  \   -236.81V

  These supply currents failed to converge:

    I(E_MULT1)                =    13.99uA  \    13.37uA
    I(X_U1.EOS)               =   253.09nA  \   250.76nA
    I(X_U1.EO4)               =  -153.14pA  \  -278.53pA

  These devices failed to converge:
    Q_Q1      X_U1.Q4   

ERROR(ORPSIM-15659): Discontinuing simulation due to convergence problem
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amplifier itself is definitely okay, you need to look elsewhere for the error. It starts to saturate above 90 mVp at 2MHz (30mV@1MHz).
[image: ad1]

[image: ad2]

Comment: I tried only op amp but it does not work, it just saturates and then simulation crashes.

Comment: Very interesting. Is the model the same as what is on the AD website? I used to have no built-in model.

Comment: I downloaded the model from AD and it still didn't work, but when I tried only op amp it did. So I changed transistor from BC807-40 to BC817-16 and now it is working. Have no idea why.

Comment: This makes it more and more interesting. I will also look at the transistors.

Comment: It works for me with both, but both BC models come from [here](https://www.diodes.com/part/view/BC817-40).

Comment: I tried BC817-40 from your link with no success, but when I add 100 ohm resistor to multiplier output then it works with any transistor or amplifier.

Comment: I see the difference, I used a [50 Ohm] (https://imgur.com/a/lUqi1EJ) internal resistance generator. Thus, the situation is similar to that of the intermediate 100 ohms.

Comment: At last we did find out, thank you for your time.